# Updating Field Based on Another Table

Tags: sql, sql-update

As someone new to SQL can you please point me in the right direction.  I know the following is wrong but I am not sure why.

```
UPDATE cus
SET cus.leg_no = new.leg_no
WHERE cus.c_no = new.c_no
```

The `cus` table currently has `null` in the `leg_no`.  I want to update it from the `new` table.  I will be joining on `c_no` which is in both tables.

I have tried searching the web but I am getting further confused. This has lead me to think I need FROM but something is telling me that is when using SELECT rather than UPDATE.

Comment: What error do you get? and Welcome to SO

Comment: Actually, just at a glance that update statement looks valid--oh, and please intend your code by 4 spaces so that it will be all _pretty-fied_--a good resource for SQL is [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

Comment: You might be able to use `FROM` - it depends on what dialect you're working with. The [tag:sql] tag is for the standard language. Could you add a tag for your specific database?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE cus,new
SET cus.leg_no = new.leg_no
WHERE cus.c_no = new.c_no
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the standard way to do it:

```
UPDATE cus
SET cus.leg_no = (select new.leg_no from new WHERE cus.c_no = new.c_no)
```

Here's the SQL Server/MS access dialect way to do it:

```
UPDATE cus
SET cus.leg_no = new.leg_no
FROM cus
  INNER JOIN new
    ON cus.c_no = new.c_no
```

Note that, with the standard method, if there are multiple rows in `new` that match a particular row from `cus`, you'll get an error message. Whereas with the SQL Server/MS access dialect form, the system will arbitrarily select one of the rows, and issue *no* warning or error.